# pygame.mouse.get_rel() only returns (0, 0)

Tags: pygame

I am trying to build a slider to change the background colour for a game and I am trying to use get_rel() to move the slider. But when I ran the code, it only returned (0, 0). How do I get it to return something other than (0, 0).
This is a piece of the code:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        time.sleep(.005)
        if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_presses = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            pygame.mouse.get_rel()
            if Knob_red.collidepoint(pos):
                time.sleep(.05)
                for even in pygame.event.get():
                    if even.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                        red_x += pygame.mouse.get_rel()[0]

                    if red_x > 783:
                        red_x = 783
                    if red_x < 515:
                        red_x = 515
```

Comment: You have multiple calls to `pygame.mouse.get_rel()` but do nothing with the return value. Each call only returns the relative movement since the last call, so multiple successive calls will start to return `(0,0)`. See the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_rel) for more details.

Comment: I edited the code and the sliders do move, but I have to do kind of a swiping motion or I have to roll the mouse wheel while dragging.

Comment: It sounds like you are not handling `MOUSEMOTION` events, only `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`. To assist you further, please edit your question to show a [mcve].

Comment: You cannot run an event loop in the event loop.

Comment: 1. Why am I not able to run an event loop within an event loop?                                           2. Like I said, I can get movement out of it, it just requires me to roll the wheel while swiping.

Comment: The loop in the event loop runs only once because there is no application loop within the event loop.

Comment: Are there any functions that I can use to increase how often it generates a mouse event, like a pygame.key.set_repeat() for the mouse? Or is it always at its fastest?

Comment: So do I need to do kind of a checking thing that if it detects that the knob is being pressed, it allows something at the end of the loop to then check for mouse motion?

Comment: And why is the knob able to move if I'm not able to run the event loop within the event loop?

Comment: @JonathanLenhart The knob is moved in the application loop. You have to use the application loop to move objects. Anyway I'm not sure what yo try to do here. Possibly the answer to the following question can help [Dragging object along x-axis in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781533/dragging-object-along-x-axis-in-pygame/61781683#61781683).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to implement an event loop inside the event loop.

All have to do is to test if any button is pressed (`any(ev.buttons)`) when the mouse is moved. The buttons and the relative movement can be get with the attributes `buttons` and `rel` from the event object.

```py
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            
            if any(ev.buttons) and Knob_red.collidepoint(ev.pos):
                red_x += ev.rel[0]
                if red_x > 783:
                    red_x = 783
                if red_x < 515:
                    red_x = 515
```